# Force user to paste only valid folder directory and disable editing directory later in TextBox control using C#

Tags: c#, textbox, directory

I am working on Windows Form Application and have created a TextBox control and a Browse button control, so that user can select a folder through Button and show directory in TextBox.

I want to give a freedom to the user to paste a directory path directly into the TextBox. However, at the same, user must provide only a valid directory as a string/text in TextBox.

In addition, I want to disable editing this directory either by keyboard or any other possible way. The user will be able to paste a new valid directory anytime but can't edit it in the TextBox.

Is there any way to do this using C# at runtime?

Thanks.

Comment: More clearly, as LukeHennerley mentioned, I want to allow Ctrl + V or Paste through Context Menu, then check if the text is a valid directory, if yes, then disable cut or edit it in any way, no keyboard, no context menu cut option. But, if the user wants to give a new directory, he/she can completely paste a new directory in TextBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the textbox to `ReadOnly` then that stops editing the `TextBox`.

Then add an event for `KeyDown` you can capture if `Ctrl + V` is pressed and then action based on that using the `Clipbboard` class and if the directory is valid set the `TextBox.Text`.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
  {
    var clipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
    if (Directory.Exists(clipboard))
      textBox1.Text = clipboard;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is a pretty nice approach to check for validation of the directory. I will give it a try right away. Thanks.

Comment: @Chetan Not a problem, I tested it in a Windows Form and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: @Chetan It works for me, are you capturing the correct event?

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, It worked fine. Pretty nice approach but still there are some other things that I want to do like disable cut, delete, modify, edit this directory once accepted. Only allow to replace it all by once. But, I think, I can do it with some modifications now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17921/discussion-between-lukehennerley-and-chetan)

Comment: Posted the modified code from your source as the answer for this question. Thanks, working well now. Please check.

Comment: sorry, it was your idea first. I just accepted the code block that I posted as it solved the problem completely. Anyways, the original idea is yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to **give a freedom to the user to paste a directory path**
>   directly into the TextBox. However, at the same, user must provide
>   only a valid directory as a string/text in TextBox.
>
> In addition, **I want to disable editing this directory** either by
>   keyboard or any other possible way. The user will be able to paste a
>   new valid directory anytime but can't edit it in the TextBox.

Isn't it contradictory ?
Why don't you use two text boxes then ? First for user to input/paste, with onchange event catching that calls a method that checks the directory's path is correct. If it is, the method copies it to the second text box, not editable, that is also linked to your directory browser.

Comment: No it isn't and this should be a comment not an answer? The OP wants to allow Ctrl + V in the textbox if what is on the clipboard is valid, but not free form typing.

Comment: No, not at all. It will not be so wise to use it like this. There must be a proper way to do this. It will just make my UI more bulky and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the [`TextChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) and check to see if the folder is valid and accessible there; if it's not, undo their change. This might not be practical if they can edit the textbox text, as it'll check to see if the folder exists after every keystroke and so typing anything new will be impossible. This might be how you want it to behave however!

To do the checking if the path is valid, I'd use [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) - pass it your textbox text and it'll throw an exception if the path doesn't exist/isn't valid/you don't have permission to access it.

If this feels a bit messy to you, instead of giving them the ability to edit the textbox, you could have a button that sets the text from the clipboard using [`Clipboard.GetText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.gettext.aspx) and then performs your checks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for suggestions and answers.
Here is something that I did and worked like a charm for me.
I hope, this will help later for someone if face the same problem.

It is the modified version of the original code posted here by LukeHennerley. Thanks LukeHennerley for that.

```
private void txtBoxTargetDir_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
        {
            var clipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
            if (Directory.Exists(clipboard))
            {
                txtBoxTargetDir.Clear();
                txtBoxTargetDir.Text = clipboard;
                txtBoxTargetDir.ReadOnly = true;
            }
            else
            {
                txtBoxTargetDir.Clear();
                txtBoxTargetDir.Text = "It's not a valid directory. Please provide a valid directory.";
            }
        }
    }
```

You will have to add this event in Form.Designer.cs first.